# LibreOffice Screen Tearing of Buttons

Tags: graphics, mate, tearing

I recently installed LibreOffice and am having screen tearing issues (I think that's the correct term). I posed a screen grab below of what it looks like. I occasionally experience it outside the application but very infrequently, so I think it is a problem specific to LibreOffice. I am running an Acer Aspire V Nitro Laptop with Ubuntu Mate.

[image: screen tearing]

Any ideas of where this problem is coming from or how I can fix this? Thanks!

Comment: That's not screen tearing. That's just bad screen formatting of objects. Screen tearing is when you are watching a fast paced movie or scene changes and the whole screen doesn't repaint in a 1/30th of a second, but half paints and a slit second later the rest paints causing a visible "tear" in the screen"

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Using openGL settings as I have displayed in the attached screenshot seemed to resolve the issue. Note: you do not need the "Office 2013" theme. This is a theme I turned on at a later time (it was not the cause of the problem).

[Screen Grab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Diin0.png)